# A query to return a row only when that row lacks a particular value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that has a structure similar to this (greatly simplified for expository purposes):

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  CUI CHAR(8),
  SAB VARCHAR(40),
  CODE VARCHAR(50),
  KEY X_CUI (CUI)
);
```

There is no primary key: there are multiple rows with the same CUI value:

```
C0000039    MSH          D015060
C0000039    NDFRT        N0000007747
C0000039    LNC          LP15542-1
C0074393    RCD          da5..
C0074393    RXNORM       36437
C0074393    SNOMEDCT_US  96211006
```

I want to find all unique CUI values that do not have a SNOMEDCT_US SAB. In the above example C0000039 would be in the result set, but C0074393 would not.

Unfortunately this exceeds my rudimentary SQL skills: could someone suggest an approach in SQL?

The full dataset contains 11,633,065 rows with 2,973,458 unique CUIs.

I am using MySQL 5.6.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct cui  
from foo where CUI not in (select distinct CUI from foo 
                     where  SAB = 'SNOMEDCT_US')
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/795ef/22)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUI 
FROM FOO 
WHERE SAB != 'SNOMEDCT_US' 
      AND CUI NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CUI FROM FOO WHERE SAB = 'SNOMEDCT_US')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: it returns both CUIs in my example because there are two rows where cui = C0074393 that have a SAB != to SNOMEDCT_US. @shree.pat18 shows this on sqlfiddle in his comment to another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
select distinct cui  
from foo
where CUI not in (select CUI 
                  from foo 
                  where  SAB = 'SNOMEDCT_US')
```

Comment: Why create a subquery? This will be more detrimental to performance than changing the where clause to <> 'SNOMEDCT_US'.

Comment: Because OP desn't want to see `C0074393`

Comment: I know. But the principle remains the same right? I might be wrong, and would be glad if you could help me understand in that case.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Now I see what I've done wrong, thanks for help! I've edited my answer!.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select distinct cui 
from tbl
where cui not in
(
 select cui from tbl  
 where sab = 'SNOMEDCT_US'
)
```

The subquery returns all values of `cui` where `sab` = 'SNOMEDCT_US'. Since these values should not be part of the final answer, we filter them out using `NOT IN`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92ddb/1)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me: I'm a bit ashamed I wasn't able to figure that one out for myself. The only change I'd make would be to use distinct on the subselect since a given CUI may have multiple SNOMEDCT_US entries (but I didn't note that in my question.) Thank you.

Comment: @TreeRex Not a problem at all, although I would encourage you to include all the relevant info (such as the one you mention above) when you post a question the next time!

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution with IN subquery works, from performance perspective it may not be the best option. Esp. if there is a lot of data to scan.

I believe that in MySQL 5.6 it is the same as in previous versions. The optimiser translates this IN subquery to a correlated subquery. And the drawback of correlated subquery - it is executed for every row. This may results in slowdown.

Depending on your needs and situation (no of rows, type of data, no of reads etc), this could be the better alternative in terms of query execution time:

```
SELECT CUI
FROM FOO
GROUP BY CUI
HAVING SUM(1) = SUM(IF(('SNOMEDCT_US') IN (SAB), 0, 1))
```

Also good to know more solutions to the same problem to have a choice :-)